# Receive Information from non-Parent Class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I have a class called "Land" and it is the parent class of School. There is another independent class "City" which contains the total population of all the land classes.

Point being School cannot inherit the information from City, is there a way that I can access City's information from class School?

My attempt was  `private City city = new City();` and then `city.Population` to extract the population information, but this didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: A concrete piece of information does not belong to a class as a whole, but to an _instance_ of that class. The class City may have a property "Population", but you can't "universally" know which is its value. An instance of City may have a population of 1,000,000 while another has a population of 3,000,000. Are you aware of this fact? You don't seem to, after reading your question. I suggest that you read a basic programming book to learn these concepts well.

Comment: Yes I agree, but unfortunately at the moment I do not have the time to do so. I would really appreciate it if you could help me, this assignment is due in five hours. The variable holding population in "City" class is Public, if that helps at all.

Comment: I can't. Fully understanding the difference between class and instance, and rephrasing your question in a way which reflects that knowledge, is a precondition for that. As it stands, it is not possible to give a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be confusing `is-a` (inheritance) and `has-a` (composition). A `School` is situated in a `City`, which in turn resides in a `Country` or `Land`. This would look like a sensible design to me:

```
class Land
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Land(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}

class City
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Land Land { get; private set; }
    public int Population { get; private set; }

    public City(string name, int population, Land land)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Population = population;
        this.Land = land;
    }
}

class School
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public City City { get; private set; }

    public School(string name, City city)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.City = city;
    }
}
```

You can use this through:

```
var land = new Land("Foo");
var city = new City("BarCity", 9001, land);
var school = new School("BazSchool", city);
```

Now you can access the population of the city the school is in by `school.City.Population`.

As you can see, we now have three classes that contain a `Name` property. You can extract this into a new (abstract) class, for example `NamedEntity`, and let all three other classes inherit from this one, as each one `is-a` named entity.

But as I get from the comments, this question was raised from a programming assignment, aimed at teaching you these principles. Yet you claim to not have time to learn this. How are you planning to finish your next programming assignment?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `public City City { get; private set; }` for consistency?

Comment: @NikitaGusev If someone posts an answer, which answers your question, you should mark it as accepted.  Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/about - it's very short and to the point.

Comment: @JohnH I guess OP doesn't have enough reputation yet to accept an answer that quickly. Anyway OP, can you perhaps answer my question?

Comment: @CodeCaster It was more a general comment, having looked through the OP's profile.